# React Native: Deep link handler doesn't fire on Pixel 6

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

The listener for deep-links successfully registers my handler:
`Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrlDeepLink);`

But on Pixel 6 for some reason the handler doesn’t fire when clicking on a deep link.
The app opens up, but nothing happens and no logs appear.

---

We use React Native v0.61.5
It's possible that it's fixed in newer versions of React Native (Linking library).
But unfortunately, currently we can't upgrade as it brings other issues.

**App.js:**

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

const handleUrlDeepLink = url => console.log(url);
Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrlDeepLink);
```